# Firebase: How can I manually restrict the Google sign in authenticator to a specific email address?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-signin

How can I use Google Sign In that is on my React.js web application only for a specific email address?

I don't wish to restrict a certain domain, but tell the authenticator that only a specific email address can register or login, and threw an error for all the others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase Authentication to limit sign-in to a specific domain or email address. However, if you upgrade to Google Cloud Identity (a paid upgrade) you can [customize the authentication flow with a blocking Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions).

Based on an example in that link:

```js
// Import the Cloud Auth Admin module.
const gcipCloudFunctions = require('gcip-cloud-functions');
// Initialize the Auth client.
const authClient = new gcipCloudFunctions.Auth();
// Http trigger with Cloud Functions.
exports.beforeCreate = authClient.functions().beforeCreateHandler((user, context) => {
  // If the user is authenticating within a tenant context, the tenant ID can be determined from
  // user.tenantId or from context.resource, eg. 'projects/project-id/tenant/tenant-id-1'
  // Only this one user can sign up.
  if (user.email !== 'user@acme.com') {
    throw new gcipCloudFunctions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', `Unauthorized email "${user.email}"`);
});
```